Mempool usecases in DPDK
I'm experimenting with DPDK and I have a question about the Mempool API. As I understand, the Mempool object is used for the rte_rings and to store rte_mbufs. I was wondering - does Mempool have another usage? For example, maybe utilize its caching mechanism to store data other than mbufs?
